# ListGroupItem and Button from react-bootstrap in the same line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

Im making my first react ptoject. Im new in JS, HTML, CSS and even web app programing.

What i try to do, is to display buttons in the same line (with some margin) with my `ListGroupItem`.

My code below (`Project.js`):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ListGroupItem, Button, ButtonToolbar } from "react-bootstrap";

class Project extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonToolbar>
        <ListGroupItem href="#link1">{this.props.project.name}</ListGroupItem>
        <Button bsStyle="primary">Primary</Button>
      </ButtonToolbar>
    );
  }
}

export default Project;
```

And an image, what i want to make:

[image]

Thanks for any advices! If you have more questions, please write in comment below

**EDIT:**

I fi added

```
.btn-toolbar {
  display: flex;
}
```

to my `App.css`, now it looks like this:

[image]

Im fine with that, i like it. but now, how to make size of that white bar static?

Comment: have you tried to use display flex?

Comment: @godfather i have no idea what r you talking about. Could u explain me what Flex is? Even i full screen, button stays below Listitem. I want to have Button and list item in same row

Comment: try to add this in your css .btn-toolbar { display: flex;}

Comment: nothing happen. Its looks likes = App.js -> ProjectsList.js -> Project.js. When i add line that u mentioned in App.css nothing happend. You must be more detailed where and what add, because im new in web development

Comment: ok you  should import the css  import "./App.css"; or create a new css file and import it

Comment: Look into my edit, it works well, thanks! You can post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.btn-toolbar { display: flex; }
```

Comment: That works fine, thanks! Could you tell me something about my edit? How to make white bar static in length? Diffrent size of it looks pretty bad

Comment: you mean the width  now changed ?

Comment: Yup, you cen see new screenshot in my edited post. I want to make whitebar static in width. Now it is flexible dependenc on string into it. I want to make it static in width

Comment: add this too a.list-group-item { width: 100%;}